Nextjs14 is not showing dynamic Metadata
The _app.tsx file has a 'generic ' that I want to show in all the pages, but there are some pages that I want to show a different one. The specific page that I want to show a different  is an Guide by id page /guides/[id]. I get the metadata using SSR from the api, and after that I set the  metadata values with the Guide values. If I use the website (example: https://migrando-blog-dev.netlify.app/guides/88) I can see first of all the generic metadata 'title', 'description', and after the SSR finished, the title changes. The problem is when I send the link by Whatsapp, it shows the 'generic' metadata, instead of the particular Guide metadata.

If I use https://opengraph.dev/panel?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmigrando-blog-dev.netlify.app%2Fguides%2F88 (Opengraph Dev) I can see the 'generic metadata'

Is there any way to 'await' until the SSR has responded and after that show the right metadata?
Here is the _app.tsx:

     return <>
        <Head>
            <title>Migrando Blog - Información para migrar</title>
            <meta name="description" content={'Encontrarás toda la información necesaria para migrar y podrás compartir tu experiencia!'} key="desc" />
            <meta
                property="og:description"
                content={'Encontrarás toda la información necesaria para migrar y podrás compartir tu experiencia!'}
            />
            <meta property="og:title" content={'Migrando Blog - Información para migrar'} />
            <meta
        property="og:image"
        content="https://migrandostoragedev.blob.core.windows.net/proyect-images/favicon.png"
      />
            <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/icons/favicon.png"></link>
        </Head>
        <ToastContainer />
        {showNotification && <p>seee</p>}
        <GoogleAnalytics trackPageViews />
        {showNotification && notification && <ToastNotification notification={notification} onClose={() => setShowNotification(false)} onClick={handleClickNotification} />}
        <RouteGuard >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </RouteGuard>

    </>

And here is the page that is not working:

    const GuideParticular = ({ guide }: { guide?: GuideListModel }) => {
    return <>
        {guide && <Head>
            <title>{guide.title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={guide.description} key="desc" />
            <meta
                property="og:description"
                content={guide.description}
            />
            <meta property="og:title" content={guide.title} />
        </Head>}
        <RootLayout>

            <div className="mx-auto p-4 md:p-10 md:-[100%] xl:w-[70%] mt-4">
                <ParticularGuide />
            </div>

        </RootLayout>
    </>

}


//@ts-ignore

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }: { params: any }) => {
    const { id } = query;
    const taskService = appContainer.get<GuideService>(TYPES.GuideService);
    try {
        if (id) {
            process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
            const task = await taskService.getCachedGuideById({ guideId: parseInt(id.toString())});

            const serializedTask = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(task?.data));
            return { props: { message: 'si', guide: serializedTask } };
        } else {
            return {
                props: {

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return {
            props :{
            }
        }
    }
};

export default GuideParticular;

The guide object is not null, I've tried removing the api call and returning hardcoded values and it doesn't work at all
